# What is the outcome of having an onclick action that submits a form on a submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, form-submit

Out of curiosity, I was wondering if there is an expected output when you have something like this:

```
    <input type="submit" onclick="document.formname.submit()">
```

I was working with a web page that someone created a few years ago and they had something similar to the above, for whatever reason. I was testing the page on the other end of the submit button, which adds things to a mySQL database. I found that it was occasionally adding everything twice, and was doing this more frequently the more items there are in the form.

Now I wonder if there is a way this is expected to work? I mostly just want to make sure that my code on the other side of the submit button is working properly. Why would this sometimes execute everything twice, and sometimes only once?

Comment: Is there a submit event handler on the form itself also?

Comment: If you are going to submit the form programmatically, you should cancel the event's default action, submitting the form, calling `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @charlietfl No, there is not.

Comment: Hard to say why anyone would add that on the button because it doesn't make sense by itself. The click event should do same thing by default

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't copy their code exactly, it was a bit more complicated. In javascript they checked a field in the form and if it was not set, they would cancel the event, and if it was set they would call submit() in javascript. Their intention, I assume, was to only submit if a certain field was filled out. I'm just curious why/how it would sometimes submit twice and sometimes only once.

Answer (score -1):

if this tag is within a `<form>` then submits the values in the form to the server side and it depends on `action` attribute of the  tag

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what the OP is asking. Are you saying that if a form does have an action attribute, it would submit the form twice?